# TIdHTTPRequestInfo.FormParams in name/value pair

Tags: delphi, indy

I am using Indy10.  My server is processing a form post.  **ARequestInfo.FormParams** properly contains the unparsed form parameters.  But **ARequestInfo.Params.count** is 0.  Is there a way I can have **ARequestInfo.Params** have the parsed form parameters?  Or is there a way to parse **ARequestInfo.FormParams**?

It seems I have to write my own parsing routine when this should already be encapsulated in the object.  Or perhaps I am missing a method.

**Update**  Doing some more digging I have found when doing a post within our LAN everything works ok.  But when the post is done from a browser outside of our LAN it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to set the `ParseParams` property at your `TIdHTTPServer`.
Or you can make a descendant of the `TIdHTTPRequestInfo` class for accessing the protected method named `DecodeAndSetParams` to parse the parameters by yourself.
Here is the example.

```
uses
  IdCustomHTTPServer;

type
  THTTPRequest = class(TIdHTTPRequestInfo);

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Request: THTTPRequest;
begin
  Request := THTTPRequest.Create;
  Request.DecodeAndSetParams('firstparam=1&secondparam=2&thirdparam=3');

  ShowMessage('Param count: ' + IntToStr(Request.Params.Count) +
              sLineBreak + sLineBreak +
              Request.Params[0] + sLineBreak +
              Request.Params[1] + sLineBreak +
              Request.Params[2] + sLineBreak
              );

  Request.Free;
end;
```

Comment: I tried that but still does not work.  But see my update about doing the Post from within the LAN and outside the LAN.  It is good to know about that property though.

Comment: It sounds like a candidate for another question. I've taken look at the `ParseParams` property implementation and it looks fine for me (I haven't tested it). If you have content type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then you should see the unparsed parameters in the `UnparsedParams` property, if something else then you should see it in the `QueryParams` property of your request.

Comment: And as you mentioned you can see the parameters unparsed (in your case of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) also in the `FormParams` property in your request info. More or less the parsing of them should work when you have the `TIdHTTPServer.ParseParams` set to True.

Comment: I will give this a look.  I recall seeing others who have experienced this problem based on the content-type.

Comment: It sounds like a problem with your network configuration to be reachable from outside of your LAN. You've asked for the parameter parser and this should work without problems ;) Try to check what's in the `ARequest.RawHeaders.Text` if you're getting some post requests from the outside. I'll delete all my comments here later on because we are talking here about totally different topic.

Comment: Ok - did some more debugging.  Went into the Indy code where it uses "ParseParams".  I am finding outside the LAN "; charset=UTF-8" is being appended to the Content-Type.  And in this particular situation it must  be exactly "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: In that case I would take focus on data you are posting on the other side. I believe that Indy's `TIdHTTPServer` header parsers works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4423/discussion-between-tlama-and-m-schenkel)

Comment: Found someone with similar issue: http://forums2.atozed.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=25734  Upgrade should fix.

Comment: @MSchenkel, has the Indy update solved your problem ? Also, it would be fine to post the Content-Type parsing issue as another question (and delete the update from this one) and answer/accept it by yourself; I think it might be helpful for the others because it's quite hidden in the forum now; at least I would vote for it. And don't forget to accept this answer if it helped you :) Anyway +1 for the question; without the update, which doesn't relate to it, it's well understandable question, so I don't get the negative here.

Comment: Yes - the update did fix the problem.  Thank you for all of your help and steering me in the right direction.